# Generate all possible 2 character combinations of a potential 8 character string?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a to generate all possible combinations of a tuple of tuples

```
( (base1 , position1) , (base2 , position2) )
```

The `bases = ["U", "C", "A", "G"]` and the `positions = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Requirements

- no repeats
- the bases can be the same but the positions must be
  different
- the order must be kept.

For example:

`( (A,1), (B,2) ) == ( (B,2) , (A,1) )` and
`( (A,1), (B,1) )` should be discarded.

Sample output:

`[ ( (U,0) , (U,1) ), ( (U,0) , (U,2) ), ( (U,0) , (U,3) ) ...]`

Should have a length of 448

---

Example:

For a string length 2:

```
((U,0),(U,1))
((U,0),(C,1))
((U,0),(A,1))
((U,0),(G,1))

((C,0),(U,1))
((C,0),(C,1))
((C,0),(A,1))
((C,0),(G,1))

((A,0),(U,1))
((A,0),(C,1))
((A,0),(A,1))
((A,0),(G,1))

((G,0),(U,1))
((G,0),(C,1))
((G,0),(A,1))
((G,0),(G,1))
```

would be all the combinations... I think

---

I have this so far

```
all_possible = []
nucleotides = ["U","C","A","G"]


for i in range(len(nucleotides)):
    for j in range(8):
        all_possible.append(((nucleotides[i],j),(nucleotides[i],j)))
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? What does the output look like specifically? I'm not certain what your example is even supposed to illustrate.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking exactly ^ but `itertools` will almost certainly have something that will help you with this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Using the `bases` and `positions` lists you give, `len([((b1, p1), (b2, p2)) for (b1, b2) in product(bases, bases) for (p1, p2) in combinations(positions, 2)])` results in 576, not 448. I think your `positions` list is too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want the Cartesian product of (every possible 2-base word)  X (every 2-combination drawn from range(8)).

You can get this in general by

```
from itertools import product, combinations

def build(num_chars, length):
    bases = ["U", "C", "A", "G"]
    for letters in product(bases, repeat=num_chars):
        for positions in combinations(range(length), num_chars):
            yield list(zip(letters, positions))
```

which gives us

```
In [4]: output = list(build(2, 8))

In [5]: len(output)
Out[5]: 448

In [6]: output[:4]
Out[6]: 
[[('U', 0), ('U', 1)],
 [('U', 0), ('U', 2)],
 [('U', 0), ('U', 3)],
 [('U', 0), ('U', 4)]]

In [7]: output[-4:]
Out[7]: 
[[('G', 4), ('G', 7)],
 [('G', 5), ('G', 6)],
 [('G', 5), ('G', 7)],
 [('G', 6), ('G', 7)]]
```